# Make X509Certificate2 Exportable

Tags: pdf, x509certificate, signature, x509, pkcs#12

I am writing a program for digitally signing a PDF document,but I have problems with certificate export,because the certificates are not exportable. But for exportable certificates my program
So,how can this problem be solved?
How Adobe Acrobat signs a document with same non-exportable certificate?

This is my code only for certificate

```
byte[] bytes = x509certificate2.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12);
```

Comment: If a certificate+key can be exported is specified when both are imported. Changing it afterwards is not possible for security reasons.

Comment: But Adobe can sign with that certificate. How?

Comment: You can use the connected private key using the cryptographic system provided by Windows but you can not export the key+certificate. Therefore if you use a library that makes use of the Windows cryptography system you can sign a PDF document  without exporting the key.